# What can I do other than wait and edit questions if I am blocked from asking for a while?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I am at a road block because I have some questions with good answers and I don't want to delete them what else can I do?

Comment: feel free to add the tags I am missing

Comment: You could write some good answers perhaps.

Comment: that won't help I can use sources not everyone can

Comment: Beware that [deleting bad questions makes the automatic qban worse, not better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/280545).

Comment: I had a bad answer and others agreed it was bad so I deleted it

Comment: @rob how would I know what stack exchange to put a question on

Comment: @chair I never got banned are you sure post ban is a suitable tag

Comment: [meta-tag:post-ban] is the appropriate tag to use for when you are blocked from asking. We call that a post ban, or a low-quality question ban. (On Stack Exchange, "bans" are automatically imposed by the system, whereas "suspensions" are usually manually imposed by moderators.)

Comment: Are you actually getting a message "We aren't accepting questions from this account"? Because your last non-deleted question appears to have a score of 4 with no downvotes, so I'm not sure how that would have triggered any mechanisms.

Comment: my questions with negative score are the ones causing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have triggered our [automatic question ban](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). The algorithm that decides whether you can post a particular question is not public, so there's not much we can advise you that you can't get from reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/280545).  But it's worth calling attention to a couple of things.

- Having low-scored questions in your history makes it more likely that you'll be prevented from asking more questions in the future.
- Having *deleted* questions in your history *also* makes it more likely that you'll be prevented from asking more questions in the future.  Resist the temptation to delete your poorly-received questions. It looks like the ones you have asked so far are safe from [the roomba](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).
- It's a very good sign that you are [actively inquiring about how to improve your questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11028/44126), and your most recent question has been well-received. Progress!  But it's worth highlighting a particular bit of advice from one of your answers there:

  > All of this takes time, hence: patience patience patience.

In all honesty, encouraging you to edit your questions and wait is the *entire point* of the automatic post bans.  As a diamond moderator, I have a little information about your post-ban status, and it looks like you've been blocked from asking several times already.  Take the hint and *wait*.  Take your draft question, save it somewhere on your own computer, and sit on it for a while.  If you waited a day before trying to post last time, wait two days the next time; if you waited two days and still got blocked, try waiting four days.  It's easier to wait if you decide in advance when you'll try to ask again.

While you're waiting, if you find yourself thinking about your question, work on improving your draft.  Spend some time searching other parts of the internet, and modify your question to be clearer about what you already know, what you've found during your searches, and what you're still confused about.  Include in your draft links to the things you've found that are useful or confusing.  Maybe you'll even [answer your own question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) before you get around to asking it!

The other thing I'd advise you do while you're waiting is to **read**.  If you have questions about stellar evolution, spend some time reading in [astronomy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy).  If you have questions about how sound works, spend some time reading in [acoustics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustics).  Look for questions that interest you and that have been well-received, where both the questions and the answers are clear.  And compare the way that those questions are written to the draft(s) of your own question(s) that you're waiting to be able to post.  Time spent reading is time spent learning how to write.

Comment: can you take a minute and read my magnet question on main?

Comment: also how is it really obvious that I can't write well?

Comment: I like constructive criticism it helps me improve

Comment: Luna, our entire interaction history has been me reading things that you have written (including your questions on main) and you reading things that I've written.  You're clearly bright, and you have interesting questions on interesting topics, but you're having trouble making yourself understood. Writing clearly is *hard*. I personally do okay at it, but it's time-consuming and tiring. The thing that most improves my own writing is reading the sorts of things that I'm trying to write. I know some professional writers who feel the same way. That's why I included the last paragraph of advice.

Comment: ok thank you for your input I will do what I can to improve future questions

Comment: quick question what do you think of my magnet question?

Comment: I am asking assuming you read it